# How to create and free a TCanvas when you have the handle?

Tags: delphi, canvas

I want to create a `TCanvas` so I can draw more easily. First I create the canvas `MyCanvas:=TCanvas.Create;`, then I get the handle `DC:=GetWindowDC(Handle);` and now what should I do... ? Should I assign directly the new handle to the canvas `MyCanvas.Handle:=DC;` or should I destroy the existing `MyCanvas.Handle` first ? And after I do the drawings I must release the handle `ReleaseDC(Handle,DC);` or if I free the canvas `MyCanvas.Free`, the handle will be released automatically ?

Comment: When in doubt - check out `HandleAllocated` property. `TCanvas` is abstract class, it does not own DC handle, so yes, you have to `ReleaseDC` on clean up.

Comment: You could use the `TControlCanvas` class which will get and release DCs for you. Its purpose is, as its name suggests, for using inside controls.

Comment: Like TLama said, I would use a TControlCanvas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a `TCanvas` it does not have a handle. Assign the handle using the DC returned by `GetWindowDC`. When you destroy the canvas, the handle is not destroyed. You need to call `ReleaseDC` explicitly.

From the [docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.Handle):

> TCanvas does not own the HDC. Applications must create an HDC and set the Handle property. Applications must release the HDC when the canvas no longer needs it. Setting the Handle property of a canvas that already has a valid HDC will not automatically release the initial HDC.